# Export txt to csv with Access DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim in VBS

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, export, export-to-csv

I have a large number of .txt files (>60k) that need to be converted to a semicolon delimited .csv (as some of the fields are a list with commas) so that I can upload them to our SQL server.

I have been successful in writing a .vbs file that will load the data into an Access db even when no table exists, but I can't get the acExportDelim to overwrite/create a new file. It also give an error when the FileName.csv does not exist.

There has to be something I am missing, but I am at a loss as to where I need to start looking.

CMD input

```
C:\Afolder\TxtToCsv.vbs \\DataOnaServer\FileName.txt \\DataOnaServer\FileName.csv
```

.vbs file

```
Dim oAccess
Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\Afolder\WDS.accdb")
oAccess.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim,"FileTxtImportSpec","FileName",WScript.Arguments.Item(0),1
oAccess.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim,"FileCsvExportSpec","FileName",WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
oAccess.Quit
```

Error message received when file is missing. (Seems I cant post the image yet)

"The Microsoft Access database engine could not fine the object 'lp4137.csv'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path correctly. If 'lp4137.csv' is not a local object, check your network connections or contact the server administrator."
Code: 800A0BC3

[Blue Claw Database Design](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/download/transfertext_outputto_examples.htm) link to a downloadable file demonstration with button click VBA running similar script.

Comment: what error do you get? Is the file stored in a path where the directory names have spaces in it?

Comment: I added the error message. There are no issues with the path as the acImportDelim is pointing to the same location.

Comment: can you check if it works if you save the csv on a local disk?

Comment: There is no difference when I move the location to my Downloads folder on C:. As well as the same error if the csv file is missing.

Comment: The process needs to be fully autonomous. If the VBA within Access can be called by CMD then I'm all for it. The export works fine if I do it manually. I just found a file from Blue Claw that is running VBA that works via button click. So I am assuming that I can just all a macro that runs the same command.

Comment: I am running this from a separate server that has programs set to run on a timer. Essentially it just needs to be able to run without human intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a good example as to why it is important to always include `Option Explicit` in your VBScript, same as you should be doing for VBA code.

Consider this VBScript.

```
WScript.Echo "TypeName(acImportDelim): " & TypeName(acImportDelim)
WScript.Echo "TypeName(acExportDelim): " & TypeName(acExportDelim)
```

Running that script in a command window returns this ...

```
C:\share\Access>cscript //NoLogo AccessNamedConstants.vbs
TypeName(acImportDelim): Empty
TypeName(acExportDelim): Empty
```

But including `Option Explicit` as the first line of that script throws an error because the Access named constants are not known to the script engine, so it assumes they must be undeclared variables.  And since `Option Explicit` treats undeclared variables as errors, there is an early warning about trouble with those named constants.

```
C:\share\Access>cscript //NoLogo AccessNamedConstants.vbs
C:\share\Access\AccessNamedConstants.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error:
 Variable is undefined: 'acImportDelim'
```

Answer (score 2):

With your vbscript you will need to specifically define the 'AcTextTransferType' enumeration.  In MS Access these enumerations are defined in the access library, and will be found. However, vbscript will not be able to recognize the enumeration values and will throw an error.

```
acExportDelim = 2
acImportDelim = 0
```

You can find the enumerations in this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194227.aspx

Comment: Just realized the solution. **VBScript likes numbers as apposed to worded commands.**
The worst part is I had run into the same issue with the TextToColumn yesterday.

Comment: It's a very easy thing to overlook with vbscript, and any late-bound objects.  I still get mixed up on it all the time.